# Simplifying chain of interleaved flatMap Observables

Tags: java, rx-java

I want to retrieve a list of objects from my repository, and then clear the contents of my repository before actually having the chance to use the retrieved list. Currently, I have several interleaved flatMaps, but I guess that there's a better way to do it. This is how my chain of Observables looks like:

```
mQueuedCallsRepository.getAll()
    .flatMap(new Func1<QueuedCallModel[], Observable<QueuedCallModel[]>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<QueuedCallModel[]> call(final QueuedCallModel[] queuedCallModels) {
            return mQueuedCallsRepository.clear()
                    .doOnNext(new Action1<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Void aVoid) {
                            disableReceiver(context);
                        }
                    })
                    .flatMap(new Func1<Void, Observable<QueuedCallModel[]>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Observable<QueuedCallModel[]> call(Void aVoid) {
                            return Observable.just(queuedCallModels);
                        }
                    });
        }
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

Any ideas how to simplify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is just fine. The only optimization is the internal `flatMap` which can be just a `map`.

```
mQueuedCallsRepository.getAll()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatMap(queuedCallModels -> {
            return mQueuedCallsRepository.clear()
                    .doOnNext(aVoid -> disableReceiver(context))
                    .map( aVoid -> queuedCallModels);
    });
```

Here is the logic:

- Get all the data and run the operation in the IO thread
- When you get the data clear (them)
- When the clear operation succeeds disable the receiver
- Then return all the data you had acquired before

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why do you need `flatMap` which does nothing:

```
new Func1<QueuedCallModel[], Observable<QueuedCallModel[]>>
```

You can use `doOnNext` operator on your root `Observable`, clear repository and then return your data:

```
Observable
        .just(new Object())
        .doOnNext(result -> System.out.println("clear"))//clearing
        .subscribe(result -> {
            //delivers result which already deleted from repository
            System.out.println("use:" + result);
        });
```

Comment: My repository class returns Observables, that means that in `doOnNext` I would have to subscribe again, something that I try to avoid. I want to have everything as a single chain :)